# Pandas plot histogram of value counts per group

Tags: pandas, histogram

I have a dataset:

```
game_id year
100     2020
100     2020
100     2020
100     2020
227     2022
227     2022
228     2023
228     2023
228     2023
...
300     2023
300     2023
301     2023
301     2023
301     2023
```

And I'd like to generate one histogram per `year` of the *distribution* of unique `game_id` values (so `df['game_id'].value_counts()`) using pandas 2.0.3.

I can manually do this using e.g. `years = df'groupby('year')` and then working with each year using `years.get_group(2023).value_counts().hist()`, but I feel like there should be a simple one-liner to pass the data to `hist()` in the correct shape to get a small multiples plot.

Comment: Folks, there is simply no correct answer that does not explicitly or implicitly involve binning the *counts* of unique `value_id` values per year. I am _not_ interested in the raw counts, I am interested in **how many times each count occurs**.

Comment: OK, but it's also your job to make things clear. For that a small schematic would be explicit. Have a look at the second part of my answer to see if this is what you want.

Comment: @mozway, Thanks, your second crosstab example is showing the correct distributions. Ideally I'd like one histogram per year (small multiples), but this is close enough.

Comment: I just edited my answer with that. It would still be great if you could add a small schematic of the expected graph in the question for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) of the counts:

```
pd.crosstab(df['game_id'], df['year']).plot.hist(alpha=0.5)
```

Output:

[image]

For separate graphs, you can use [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.displot(data=df.value_counts().reset_index(name='count'),
            x='count', col='year', kind='hist')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This isn't quite right, as it's not plotting the *binned counts* of unique `game_id` values. The `x` axis in your examples is showing the values themselves (e.g. 100, 227, 301).

Comment: @urschrei I see, then this is not a **hist** but a **bar** plot, let me update

Comment: If this is not what you want, please provide a schematic.

Comment: @ mozway The data example I'm showing you is correct – the fact that the `game_id` values are numeric is a coincidence. I'm interested in a by-year breakdown of the _distribution_ of the unique `game_id` *value counts*: so in 2022 the `100` id has a count of 4, and in 2023 the `228` id has a value of 3 etc.

Comment: @urschrei the barplot provided above does meet the requirements you stated. Note that id 100 in the year 2020 has value count of 4.

Comment: @Onyambu I miscounted that id, yes, but that doesn't make the answer correct. It _cannot_ be correct: a histogram plots binned values, not the actual counts.

Comment: That's why I requested a mockup of the expected graph. If the game_id is categorical then a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) doesn't make sense, you would need a **numeric** variable. Or do you want a histogram of the counts? `pd.crosstab(df['game_id'], df['year']).plot.hist()`

Comment: @urschrei you cannot have a histogram of categorical values. Your game_id is a categorical value. You can have a histogram of numerical, preferably continuous values. Either you need a barplot, or you need to provide the values of which the histogram will be plotted. Notice that in your code you are doing `value_count()` meaning computing the count rather than the binned count which is just a barplot

Comment: @Onyambu I think OP wants a histogram of the counts per year, which wasn't clear…